# How to Remove version number from file name with Maven Build in Spring Boot 2.1.4 version?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade Spring Boot from 2.0 to 2.1.4. When building the application as war file

***In 2.1.4 - getting the version number in build filename like as shown below:***

War filename : `demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bootified.war`

***But in 2.0 - not getting the version number in build filename like as shown below:***

War filename: `demo-bootified.war`.

Please find the plugin as shown below:

pom.xml:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.java.main.test.DemoApplication</mainClass>
            <classifier>bootified</classifier>
            <build><finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName></build>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                  <goal>repackage</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

How to remove the version in build filename in 2.1.4 Spring Boot version? Please suggest on this?

Comment: You need to add  `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` under `<build>  </build>`

Comment: I tried by adding build as `<build><finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName></build>` even result is same. and also updated my post. Please check and help me on this. Thanks. @Pratapi Hemant Patel

Comment: No, not like that, <build> should be at top above <plugins> See this https://github.com/hemantsonu20/tropo-record-example/blob/master/pom.xml#L58

Comment: version 2.1.3 works as expected, the build/finalName is taken into account, unfortunately the 2.1.4 version ignores the setting.  I am trying to find out if it is a bug or a feature

Answer (score 0):

Althogh it worked in previous versions (up to 2.1.3), the behavour is now to include the version.  See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16457 for more info.  Use standard Maven  to provide your artifact's final name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your execution configuration:
               
                `<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                </executions>`

Comment: <fileName> inside <configuration> of spring blugin won't work anymore in 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add `<finalName>` in your `<build>` section. For example:

```
<build>
...
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

...
</build>
```